# Creating StackDriver Dashboards programmatically

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

I am setting a an custom application which sends metrics StackDriver using Prometheus. Now I have all my metrics under customer metrics "external/prometheus".
I have setup the dashboard for the application metrics from Stackdriver UI. But I have many of the applications which are on boarding to Stackdriver and I would like create the dashboards programmatically whenever required instead of navigating UI every time. are there APIs to do it already? if so can someone please share some samples to get started?

Comment: You can create one dashboard and you can use this dashboard as a template to create other dashboards. There is a way to create new dashboard by copying from existing dashboard. Just the namespace information needs to be changed.